# Duplicate in n-to-n relationship in ssas cube

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, olap-cube

I have a cube with the structure of n-to-n relationship to categories.

Each product can belong to many categories. In this scenario my product table looks like this:

[image]

There is one product in 3 different categories:

1. Fashion

   - Men
   - Women
2. Electronic

The Bridge_ProductCategories has 3 rows for mapping each category to this product. So I have 3 records in FactSales table showing the sales amount of this product.

In cube browsing when I filter the "Electronic" category, everything works fine.

But when I filter "Fashion" category, because of the belonging to 2 subcategories, the sales amount will be duplicated.

[image: Fashion Result]

Does anyone have any solution for this situation?